# Flutter simulator reads and writes Firestore data but physical ios device only writes. Running the app to the physical device from XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, webkit

I'm using Google, Apple, Facebook, and email sign-in methods, and those all work. They create documents correctly. The documents show the UID as well, so they're fine, but none of the profiles read/retrieve the documents. Also, the simulator works perfectly.

I am, however, getting WebKit errors in XCode while running the app.

These are the errors:
[ProcessSuspension] 0x125084120 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'ConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=33537, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}>
[ProcessSuspension] 0x125084180 - ProcessAssertion: Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=33537, error: Error Domain=RBSAssertionErrorDomain Code=2 "Specified target process does not exist" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Specified target process does not exist}

No data is being returned from Firestore (I have many stream requests for data from Firestore), but I've included the user settings request.

```
    class UserSettings extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserSettings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static String id = 'userSettings';

  @override
  State<UserSettings> createState() => _UserSettingsState();
}

class _UserSettingsState extends State<UserSettings> {
  late User loggedInUser;
  String imageUrl = '';
  bool isWaiting = true;

  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _usersStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('users')
      .where('UID', isEqualTo: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid)
      .snapshots();

  //get users => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _usersStream,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return const Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return const CircularProgressIndicator();
        }

        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: const Text('User Settings'),
            leading: const Text(''),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                  Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(context,'/',(_) => false);
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: const [
                    Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.signOutAlt, size: 20),
                    SizedBox(width: 7.0),
                    Text('Sign Out'),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          body: ListView(
            children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
              Map<String, dynamic> data =
              document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
              final erImageCard = (data['image_url']);
              final erNameCard = (data['er_name']);
              final erEmailCard = (data['er_email']);
              final blogNameCard = (data['blog_name']);
              final blogUrlCard = (data['blog_url']);
              final erInstagramCard = (data['instagram']);
              final erTwitterCard = (data['twitter']);
              final erFacebookCard = (data['facebook']);
              final erOtherSocialCard = (data['other_social']);
              final erSharesCard = (data['share_s']);

              const cardHeaderName = 'er Name';
              const cardHeaderEmail = 'er Email';
              const cardHeadBlogName = 'Blog Name';
              const cardHeadBlogUrl = 'Blog Url';
              const cardHeadInstagram = 'https://instagram.com/...';
              const cardHeadTwitter = 'https://twitter.com/...';
              const cardHeadFacebook = 'https://facebook.com/...';
              const cardHeadOtherSocial = 'Other Social Media';
              const cardHeadShares = 'Share s';

              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      children: [

                        CircleAvatar(
                           /* child: MaterialButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).push(
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (_) => UserImage(
                                      onFileChanged: (String imageUrl) {
                                        setState(
                                          () {
                                            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              child: const Icon(
                                FontAwesomeIcons.userEdit,
                                size: 43.0,
                              ),
                            ),*/

                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                            },
                          ),
                            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context)
                                .primaryColor
                                .withOpacity(0.4),
                            foregroundImage:
                                NetworkImage(erImageCard),
                            radius: 50.0,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                    Divider(
                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor.withOpacity(0.5),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4:
                          erName(erName: erNameCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeaderName,
                      settingsCardDetail: erNameCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4:
                          erEmail(erEmail: erEmailCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeaderEmail,
                      settingsCardDetail: erEmailCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4: BlogName(blogName: blogNameCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeadBlogName,
                      settingsCardDetail: blogNameCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4: BlogURL(blogUrl: blogUrlCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeadBlogUrl,
                      settingsCardDetail: blogUrlCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4: erInstagram(
                          erInstagram: erInstagramCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeadInstagram,
                      settingsCardDetail: erInstagramCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4: erTwitter(
                          erTwitter: erTwitterCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeadTwitter,
                      settingsCardDetail: erTwitterCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4: erFacebook(
                          erFacebook: erFacebookCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeadFacebook,
                      settingsCardDetail: erFacebookCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4:
                          OtherSocial(otherSocial: erOtherSocialCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeadOtherSocial,
                      settingsCardDetail: erOtherSocialCard,
                    ),
                    SettingsListCard(
                      pushedcontext4: Shares(
                          shares: erSharesCard),
                      settingsCardHeader: cardHeadShares,
                      settingsCardDetail: erSharesCard
                          .toString()
                          .replaceAll('0', 'Yes')
                          .replaceAll('1', 'No'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }).toList(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add some code and the error that you are getting.

Comment: I actually wouldn't know what code to add, but I've added the errors above. I don't quite understand why it works in the simulator, nor why it adds data to Firestore. I do use indexing in Firestore, so not sure if this causes a problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've managed to fix it by uninstalling XCode 13.3 and installing XCode 13.2. Also, I had to delete all the data from ~Library\Developer\XCode\DerivedData.